# How to attach a Notes document in Email using Lotus script

Tags: embed, lotus-notes, lotusscript

How to attach or embed IBM Notes document in the email using Lotus Script.

I need to compose and send a email with a number of documents (bills) as embedded documents or attachments but not links. The user selects one or more documents from a view and clicks "Email Bills To Customers" and the application will loop through each customer document, looks up their bill documents and collects them as attachments with this email. The challenging part is how to create the notes documents as attachment or embedded notes document, pdf or images (whatever is possible). I want the solution in IBM Lotus script.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use NotesDocument's method [RenderToRTItem](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_RENDERTORTITEM_METHOD.html). It will create a "picture" of the document and put it into a RichTextField.

Collect such a "picture" of all your bills and put those into the final RichtText item with [AppendRTItem](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_APPENDRTITEM_METHOD.html) (and probably [AddPageBreak](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_ADDPAGEBREAK_METHOD_290_ABOUT.html)).

Comment: Cool. Let me try it. Thanks

Comment: For some reason I'm unable to send email working from home. Though it works (sending email) fine from office. 

I left this part for now until Monday and created a memo with necessary code and used RenderToRTItem method of NotesDocument then saved the document to take a peek into the document. I used a view with ALL documents. The document is empty but it shows the entire bill information when viewing "Body" through the document properties (2nd tab). Looks like the bill information is saved but the form or the table is not.

Comment: The code solution with "RenderToRTIte" seems to work and the bill is shown with proper formatting but only if the recipient email account belongs to IBM cloud (our official accounts are on IBM cloud). For the other recipients (hotmail, gmail etc.) the bill is shown in distorted form, with no design layout.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider this tool: [Swing Software PDF Converter](https://www.swingsoftware.com/pdf-converter/overview).

It is commercial software, but it is probably your best option if you want actual file attachments instead of just rendering the rich text of multiple documents into the body of your message.  And yes, it does have an [API](https://sites.google.com/a/swingsoftware.com/lc/pdf-converter/for-developers) that you can use from LotusScript.

Answer (score 0):

We use PDFCreator > https://www.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator

Unlike the Swing offering it's Open Source and always being updated, and dead easy to control via LotusScript to print and attach PDF's.